# How to export sorted data using mongoexport?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongo which has name and count fields.

```
{name:'myName',count:5}
```

Is it possible to sort data by count and export as json using mongoexport?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually you can, but you have to use special params. Here's a sample (redirecting to file):

```
$ mongoexport  -q '{ $query: {count: {$gt:0}}, $orderby: {count: -1} }' -d database -c collection > data_dump.json
```

The $query part is not strictly necessary, but I included it because of [this bug](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/pull/207) on GitHub (fixed now, but only just).

Comment: @rowanu: Hey, is this possible for group by queries?

Comment: The solution by @rowanu doesn't works for me, but this one does: `--query '{ $query: {}, $orderby: {count: -1} }' --forceTableScan`

Comment: Yeah, my solution is nearly two years old, and was done on MongoDB version 2.0 (current stable version is 2.4, with 2.6 coming out soon) so that's not surprising.

Comment: Not sure if that bug was fixed - see [this issue I filed](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12665).

Comment: orderBy was deprecated. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48051096/5986661 and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/

Answer (score 40):

Starting with MongoDB 2.6, you can pass `--sort` to [`mongoexport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/program/mongoexport/) directly:

```
mongoexport --db mydatabase -c people --fields name,age --sort "{name: 1, age: 1}"
```

Answer (score -9):

You can't pass in an argument to sort your documents by a specific key when using mongoexport.

The way to do this would be to write your own script.

Hope this helps.

Comment: [Yes you can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22952270/1269037); please delete this answer.