# Convert MongoDB query to mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I have the following Mongo query

```
db.CustUser.find(
{"transactionData": {"$elemMatch": {"createdAt": {"$lte": ISODate("2013-07-15T00:00:00Z")}}}, "emailsSubscribed": true},
{"fname": 1, "email": 1, "_id": 0}).limit(150000).sort({"_id": -1})
```

I'm trying to export the results to CSV. Is mongoexport capable of such a query? Any help is appreciated.

Using MongoDB version 2.2.3

Comment: If not, I'll just go ahead and write a script. More/less curious if mongoexport can be used in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Mongoexport version 2.2.x can do some of this - the query and the sort. It does not support limit - that option is supported in version 2.6.

The query is passed as a json document to mongoexport:

> **--query**
>
> ```
> Provides a JSON document as a query that optionally limits the documents returned in the export.
> ```

You can sort via a $orderby (undocumented but here's a good discussion on it):

[How to export sorted data using mongoexport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005983/how-to-export-sorted-data-using-mongoexport)

and example:

```
--query '{ $query: {}, $orderby: {count: -1} }'
```

Limit is not supported until version 2.6:

> **--limit**
>
> ```
> Specifies a maximum number of documents to include in the export. See limit() for information about the underlying operation.
> ```

2.6 also has different syntax for sort:

> **--sort**
>
> ```
> Specifies an ordering for exported results. If an index does not exist that can support the sort operation, the results must be less
> ```
>
> than 32 megabytes.
>
> ```
> Use --sort conjunction with --skip and --limit to limit number of exported documents.
> ```

Links:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoexport/